# Mappings that are not functors in category theory

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let **C** be a category and let $F$ be a mapping on **C**. Assume that $F$ is defined for all objects of **C**. However, on the arrows of **C** the mapping $F$ does not always behave like a (covariant) functor. For example, it may be the case that for some arrow $f: x \rightarrow y$ in **C**, the mapping $F$ returns an arrow $F(f): F(x)\rightarrow F(y)$ in **C**. For another arrow $g:a \rightarrow b$ in **C**, the mapping $F$ may return an arrow $F(g): F(b)\rightarrow F(a)$ in ${\bf C}^{op}$. And possibly for other arrows of **C**, the mapping $F$ may not even be defined. Such a mapping is neither covariant not contravariant and it may also be partial. Is there a special name for such mappings?

Comment: What's the example you have in mind?

Comment: Take for example a partially ordered set $(P,\sqsubseteq)$, which gives rise to a category. Consider a function $F: P \rightarrow P$. Such functions can be monotone, anti-monotone, or neither. It seems that in category theory we are mainly interested in covariant functors (ie., monotone functions) and contravariant functors (ie., anti-monotone ones).  Is there a more general notion than just covariant/contravariant? Or is this just called ``a mapping''? I am new to category theory, so I apologize if my question sounds pedantic.

Comment: This simply corresponds to a function between the object-classes of the two categories.

Comment: But what if we are also interested in the effect that such a function has on arrows (and only on objects)?

Comment: Do you have a concrete example in mind that is not an example of a covariant functor, a contravariant functor, or a function between object-classes?

Comment: Not something specific. But, for example, functions from sets to sets are not always either monotone or anti-monotone.

Comment: But in these cases, the posetal structure is irrelevant. It's difficult to suggest a definition without any motivating examples.